# phpMyAdmin and Django on same Apache server when redirecting to phpmyadmin I get 403 error access forbidden

Tags: apache

I'm running a django project on opensuse and working fine and I installed phpMyAdmin before  was working fine before django installation, I then configured django and phpMyAdmin to run on same apache server and added this configuration of phpMyAdmin to apache

`Alias /phpMyAdmin /srv/www/hotdocs/phpMyAdmin/
    <Directory /srv/www/htdocs/phpMyAdmin>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Location /phpMyAdmin>
        SetHandler None
    </Location>`

I get this error when redirecting to url/phpMyAdmin

> Access forbidden!
>
> You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no >index document or the directory is read-protected.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 403

If Anybody can help me in this error!! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Probably you dont have access to the htdocs or the phpmyadmin folder. You need to assign user read/write access. Like this

```
sudo chmod -R 666 /opt/path
```

or any other path.

Comment: thank you very much for your help ... but it doesn't work it seems that the path of phpMyAdmin is wrong !!! how can I know the right path of phpMyAdmin ??? please if you can help

Comment: Most probably it will be located inside the /etc folder, since you are not using the lampp stack hence you can check that out. This link might help you https://help.ubuntu.com/community/phpMyAdmin

Comment: thank you very much for your help.. you were right thank you